# WordPress userpro shortcode login logout register working links

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

I'm using this code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[userpro_loggedout]Login | Register[/userpro_loggedout][userpro_loggedin]Welcome, [first_name] [last_name] ! | Logout[/userpro_loggedin]'); ?>
```

Using userpro but its displaying as a text. I want the links to be functional so that **the text on which user can click to logout, login, or register** and have that action happen.

How can I do this?

Comment: So what does the code do right now and/or what is the behaviour right now? This might help other users to answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it is fixed now..now its working fine..And If I need help in some other coding matter, I will ask..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have login page created for userpro.

Then you can just use link like:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/your-login-url">login</a>
```

and for logout url you would need :

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a>
```

You might also need to wrap all of that into if statement to check which url should be displayed based on user's login status:

```
<?php if(is_user_logged_in()) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url(); ?>">Logout</a>
<?php } else { ?>
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/your-login-url">login</a>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: mmm thx Nick but userpro has its default login page n logout n register pages,, this above shortcode which i used its working fine without working link ,,like when u r login it display only welcome, n logout text n if u r not login it shows login and register text but these r just texts not working links ,,userpro as far as i know it has shortcodes but these shortcodes only disply a templates i dnt wnat the whole template i just need links which i already placed in navigation area.

Comment: So you need to create a page and add userpro login shortcode which will show the login form. Then the url of this page will be the login page url which you can use in the links.

Comment: .i just want links which takes user to their desired pages like if user click on login it takes user to the login page which is default userpro login page ...!!

Comment: mmmmm rite good idea thanks bro i try this and then i let u know !! :):)